# Particle hair growing in a weird direction

Tags: particles, hair

I created a particle system in my object and the hairs are growing in a weird direction... I tried to change the rotation but nothing happens (they don't rotate at all). I want them to be orientated in the z direction. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear what's 'weird' about the direction.  Your hairs are growing in the direction expected, assuming you have the emitter set to the object face.  That is they're growing out from the front of the face.  If you want both rings hairs growing in the same direction you need to flip normals on one of the faces.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear. I want them to grow in the z direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hairs grow from the faces of the two rings in the direction that the normals are facing.  If you view normals in edit mode (by turning on the overlay

[image: view normals overlay]

[image: overlay enabled]

and setting the normal length) I suspect you will see something like this:

[image: rings with normals showing]

You want the normals from the top ring to face down.  To do that select all of the faces in the top ring and type SHIFT-N to recalculate normals.  If they're still facing up, open  the action box (in the lower left of the 3d view) and enable inside:

[image: top selected]

[image: recalculate normals with inside selected]

and you should see something like this:

[image: normals shifted]

Now your hair should grow down from both rings

[image]